# I am trying to click on Login link, and ai() function is clicking on Register link in zerostep playwright

Tags: typescript, sockets, automation, node-modules, playwright

I am trying to click on Login link of the webapp
http://eaapp.somee.com/
through zerostep playwright with the script "await ai('Click on the Login link in the header', { page, test })"
This clicks on the Register button instead of Login. How can I debug that what went wrong here?
The code written is:

```
test('has title', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('http://eaapp.somee.com/');

  /* Expect a title "to contain" a substring. */
  await ai('Verify that title contains Execute Automation', {page, test})
  await ai('Hover on to Login link', {page, test})
  await ai('Click on the Login link in the header', {page, test})
  await ai('Fill the fields with realistic values', {page, test})

});
```

My package.json file is

```
{ "devDependencies": { "@playwright/test": "^1.40.1", "@types/node": "^20.10.4", "@zerostep/playwright": "^0.1.5", "playwright": "1.40.1" }, "scripts": { "test": "npx playwright test" } }
```

I tried printing the logs of ai(functions) running, the logs I am getting are

> ws send: {"type":"task-start","packageVersion":"v0.1.5","taskId":"018c5db5-004b-7bfe-ad1c-47850643b9a8","task":"Verify that title contains Execute Automation","snapshot":{"dom":"{"documents":[{"documentURL":0,"title":1,"baseURL":0,"contentLanguage":
> < ws recv: {"type":"task-complete","taskId":"018c5db5-004b-7bfe-ad1c-47850643b9a8","model":"gpt-3.5-turbo","wasSuccessful":true,"result":{"assertion":false}}
> ws send: {"type":"task-start","packageVersion":"v0.1.5","taskId":"018c5db5-1381-740c-86b6-981c04b62564","task":"Hover on to Login link","snapshot":{"dom":"{"documents":[{"documentURL":0,"title":1,"baseURL":0,"contentLanguage":-1,"encodingName":2,
> < ws recv: {"type":"command-request","taskId":"018c5db5-1381-740c-86b6-981c04b62564","index":0,"name":"hoverElement","arguments":{"id":"73"}}
> ws send: {"type":"command-response","packageVersion":"v0.1.5","taskId":"018c5db5-1381-740c-86b6-981c04b62564","index":0,"result":"null"}
> < ws recv: {"type":"task-complete","taskId":"018c5db5-1381-740c-86b6-981c04b62564","model":"gpt-3.5-turbo","wasSuccessful":true,"result":{"actions":["Hover"]}}
> ws send: {"type":"task-start","packageVersion":"v0.1.5","taskId":"018c5db5-1b0c-7508-9555-141536f29a1b","task":"Click on the Login link in the header","snapshot":{"dom":"{"documents":[{"documentURL":0,"title":1,"baseURL":0,"contentLanguage":-1,"enc
> < ws recv: {"type":"command-request","taskId":"018c5db5-1b0c-7508-9555-141536f29a1b","index":1,"name":"clickElement","arguments":{"id":"73"}}
> ws send: {"type":"command-response","packageVersion":"v0.1.5","taskId":"018c5db5-1b0c-7508-9555-141536f29a1b","index":1,"result":"null"}
> < ws recv: {"type":"task-complete","taskId":"018c5db5-1b0c-7508-9555-141536f29a1b","model":"gpt-3.5-turbo","wasSuccessful":true,"result":{"actions":["Click"]}}
> ws send: {"type":"task-start","packageVersion":"v0.1.5","taskId":"018c5db5-24f0-7453-b031-966813fefde3","task":"Fill the fields with realistic values","snapshot":{"dom":"{"documents":[{"documentURL":0,"title":1,"baseURL":0,"contentLanguage":-1,"enc

Comment: What's `await ai('Click on the Login link in the header', { page, test })`? Please share a [mcve] showing your full code. I'd use `page.getByText("Login", {exact: true}).click()`.

Comment: await ai() is the ai function of zerostep integrated with playwright. ai() function is using chat-GPT 3.5 and chat-GPT 4 to ease the automation process. 
Here is the full code of the Login function

test('has title', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('http://eaapp.somee.com/');
  await ai('Verify that title contains Execute Automation', { page, test })
  await ai('Hover on to Login link', {page, test})
  await ai('Click on the Login link in the header', { page, test })
  await ai('Fill the fields with realistic values', { page, test })
});

Comment: Please [edit] the post when you want to add code. Why do you need AI to click a login link? That sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @ggorlen I am just trying a new tool and I am curious about its debugging properties, that how can we debug something here. Not alone about the login, but let's say we are doing some other case, and we face this same scenario there, then how can I debug what went wrong?

Comment: It's a reasonable question (I'd provide a site under test and your package.json as well so the example is complete), but the tool seems fundamentally suspicious. LLMs hallucinate all the time and/or simply misinterpret the prompt. I haven't used it, but it seems pretty sketchy. The library should tell you what code it's wound up generating so you can debug it. Maybe LLMs are useful for generating the initial code, which you can then verify and run deterministically, but using them for every call seems like a roll of the dice, not suitable for testing. Anyway, good luck with the debug here.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's a paid tool too, another reason I'm not going to use this.

Comment: Yes Its a paid tool, and It has some free functions, so just exploring it.